# Error: 500 When registering data using webService

Tags: java, rest, web-services

When registering data in my database using webservice the following error occurs.

```
    Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir
    Post parameters : {"login":"felipe10","senha":"1234","email":"teste@gmail.com","perfil":"teste100"}
     Response Code : 500
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at 



 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at consumindows.HttpExemplo.sendPost(HttpExemplo.java:165)
at consumindows.HttpExemplo.main(HttpExemplo.java:50)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at consumindows.HttpExemplo.sendPost(HttpExemplo.java:159)
... 1 more
 C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
 FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 1 segundo)
```

Class executing s data insertion.

```
package consumindows;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.Proxy.Type;
 import java.net.URL;
 import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
 import modelo.Usuario;


 public class HttpExemplo {

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    HttpExemplo http = new HttpExemplo();

    Gson g =new Gson();
    Usuario u = new Usuario();

    java.lang.reflect.Type usuarioType= new TypeToken<Usuario>() {}.getType();
    String url;


  u.setEmail("teste@gmail.com");
 u.setLogin("felipe10");
 u.setPerfil("teste100");
 u.setSenha("1234");
  System.out.println(u.getLogin()); 

   String json=g.toJson(u, usuarioType);


 url="http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir";
       http.sendPost(url,json,"POST");
   }

  // HTTP POST request
 private void sendPost(String url,String urlParameters,String method) throws         Exception {

   URL obj= new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
//add reuqest header
 con.setRequestMethod(method);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");



  // Send post request
  con.setDoOutput(true);
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
  wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
  wr.flush();
   wr.close();

   int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
 System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
 System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
 response.append(inputLine);
 }
 in.close();

  //print result
  System.out.println(response.toString());

       }


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're attempting to do here but I at least tidied up the code a bit and removed some redundancy to make it clearer...

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Proxy.Type;
import java.net.URL;

import modelo.Usuario;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class HttpExemplo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpExemplo.class);
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpExemplo http = new HttpExemplo();

        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setEmail("teste@gmail.com");
        user.setLogin("felipe10");
        user.setPerfil("teste100");
        user.setSenha("1234");
        log.info("Usario: {}", user.getLogin());

        Type usuarioType = new TypeToken<Usuario>() {}.getType();

        String json = GSON.toJson(user, usuarioType);

        URL url =  new URL("http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir");
        http.post(url, json);
    }

    private void post(URL url, String json) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(json);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        log.info("Sending 'POST' request to URL: {}", url);
        log.info("Post json: {}", json);
        log.info("Response Code: {}", responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        log.info(response.toString());

        in.close();
    }
}
```